# Logical operator || not outputting everything (JSX)

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements, jsx, logical-operators

As far as i understand if either conditions "mobileNumber" or "AuthUser" is true, whatever is in the ( ) should be outputted

```
<>
  {mobileNumber &&(
              <List.Item>
                  <Icon 
                  className="phone icon" 
                  />
                  <ListContent>
                      {mobileNumber}
                  </ListContent>
              </List.Item>
  )}
</>
```

Above outputs everything correctly

```
<>
  {mobileNumber || AuthUser(
              <List.Item>
                  <Icon 
                  className="phone icon" 
                  />
                  <ListContent>
                      {mobileNumber}
                  </ListContent>
              </List.Item>
  )}
</>
```

This, if both are true, outputs the {mobileNumber} inside the ListContent, but the icon (and seemingly everything else in the paranthesis ) disappears

Why is this? Can i fix it? I researched here and on the internet, everything says that if either is true, what is in the paranthesis is outputted.

Comment: What is `AuthUser(...` fn?

Comment: A const that tells if the user is logged in or not. const { AuthUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

Comment: I see then, is `{mobileNumber || AuthUser(..` correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should wrap `or` expression evaluation followed by `&&` operator, like `{( conditionA || conditionB ) && (<>your content</>)`:

```
{(mobileNumber || AuthUser) && (
              <List.Item>
                  <Icon 
                  className="phone icon" 
                  />
                  <ListContent>
                      {mobileNumber}
                  </ListContent>
              </List.Item>
  )}
```